# Adding a newline to AWS SNS message in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns

I want to send AWS SNS notification through shell script in EC2. The following is my command:

```
aws sns publish --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:x:x:x \
  --region=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION \
  --subject "Processing Error - ${tablename}" \
  --message "An error has occurred in API data processing. The error file ${error_file} has been written to the errors folder...The file contents of ${error_file} are : $(cat ${error_file})"
```

My problem is that I don't know how can I insert a newline before I printing the content of file using "`cat`" command? I want to print the content of the file after a newline. Now it gets appended to `"The file contents of ..."`.

How do I add a newline into the `--message` parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inserting the literal newline character

```
aws sns publish --message="...
$(cat ${error_file})" # other options
```

In Bash/Ksh93/Zsh:

```
aws sns publish --message="..."$'\n'"$(cat ${error_file})" \
  # other options
```

Using `printf`:

```
aws sns publish --message="$(printf "%s\n%s" "..." "$(cat ${error_file})")" \
  # other options
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ruslan...the solutions were helpful & the problem got solved